# Android Video - Flash is Dead, is HTML5 the only option to play videos?

Tags: android, flash, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm developing an app for android that plays mp4 video files from the web. My problem is that I initially relied on adobe flash player to play the videos but a couple of weeks ago adobe stopped developing flash for android mobile devices and my only option is now html5, is this right ?
What's the best approach to play mp4 videos via html5 on mobile devices?
Should I use the html5 code inside a "WebView" like i did with flash or is there another option for this?

I'm kinda lost here, any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a native Android app then you shouldn't need to rely on Flash or a `WebView` to play mp4 videos in Android at all.  You should use the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class, as discussed in the [Android  SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

You can use that to play your video, so long as you content conforms to the list of [supported protocols and formats/codecs](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).  Which mp4 files delivered over HTTP almost certainly do, assuming they're using the H.264 video codec, and a non-crazy audio format.

Comment: This is correct. As a general rule, web/HTML interfaces on Android are much slower and buggier than doing them with the Android APIs.